# Time Series Forecast in R - Weekly Sparse Data with Variable Starting Point

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, forecasting

I am working on building a time series forecast model for a problem which involves dataset of manufacturers and their product offerings in a large retail outlet.

The problem is as follows:

1. Lets say you have thousands of manufacturers. (M1 to Mn)
2. There is a retail outlet who would take goods from these
   manufacturers to sell.
3. The manufacturers supply product offerings to the store on weekly
   basis.(same product or new product with same price or different
   price, but for simplicity lets say they supply new distinct
   products) (from week W1 to Wn)
4. Each manufacturer would have started working with the retail outlet
   on different dates.(which can be anything in past)
5. From the time they started working with the retail outlet, the
   history suggests that some manufacturers have been constantly
   supplying products weekly and some have been sparse.

> In Dataset Below (N/A means they hadn't started doing business with
>   the retail outlet e.g manufacturer M1 joined the retailer on Week3 in
>   our time window with their first offering count to be 10)

```
       W1 -  W2 -  W3 -  W4 -  W5 - W6 - W7 - W8 - . - . - . - Wn 
M1 - | N/A | N/A | 10  | 0   | 5  | 0  | 10 | 15 | 12 | . | . | 23 |
M2 - | 10  | 5   | 12  | 8   | 4  | 9  | 0  | 0  | 0  | . | . | 4  |
M3 - | 9   | N/A | 0   | 0   | 45 | 45 | 45 | 38 | 12 | . | . | 11 |
 . - | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A | 12 | 0  | 10 | 15 | 12 | . | . | 28 |
 . - | N/A | N/A | N/A | 0   | 5  | 0  | 8  | 15 | 12 | . | . | 12 |
 . - | 5   | N/A | 60  | 0   | 5  | 0  | 40 | 67 | 23 | . | . | 46 |
 . - | N/A | N/A | 12  | 9   | 12 | 15 | 10 | 15 | 43 | . | . | 9  |
Mn - | 0   | N/A | 90  | 78  | 65 | 0  | 10 | 15 | 12 | . | . | 65 |
```

Now assuming that for all the manufacturers, I want to forecast, from the point Wn their next 8 weeks of supply they would do from this historical data ( i.e. from Wn for next 8 weeks i..e Wn+1 to Wn+8).

I am trying to forecast using the Auto ARIMA and seasonal naive models in R.

```
tsfull<- ts(tsdata, start=c(ts_series_strt_dt,weeknum_strt), freq=52)

tswindow<- window(tsdata, start=c(ts_series_strt_dt,weeknum_strt), end=c(ts_series_end_dt,weeknum_end)) 

SN<-snaive(tswindow, 8)
AR<-forecast.Arima(auto.arima(tswindow), h=8)
etsfr<-forecast(ets(tswindow), h=8)
stlffr<-forecast(stlf(tswindow), h=8)
```

Since the data contains a lot of Zeros, also since the starting point of the series for every manufacturer is totally different, also we have thousands of manufacturers and I see the RMSE error varies erratically since each series is unique. Also I have tried grouping the manufacturer based on their age with the outlet. I am not able to decide on the best forecast model that would fit this problem.

I am not an expert in this field. Any thoughts and opinion would be really helpful.